# Render glitch with custom block boundaries minecraft

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm creating a mod for Minecraft.  Recently, I've tried to make a custom block, and I'm having two issues with it.

My main issue is that the block is rendering incorrectly.  I want the block to be smaller in size than a full block.  I successfully changed the block boundaries with `setBlockBounds()`, and while that *did* make the block render smaller and use the smaller boundaries, it causes other rendering issues.  When I place the block, the floor below is becomes invisible and I can see through it, either to caves below, blocks behind it, or the void if there is nothing there.  How do I fix that block not rendering?  Here's a screenshot:

> [image]

Additionally, my goal for this block is to emit an "aura" that gives players around it speed or some other potion effect. I have the basic code for finding players around the block and giving them speed, but I can't find a way to activate this method every tick or every X amount of ticks to ensure that it gives players within the box speed in a reliable manner.  There are already some blocks in the normal game that do this, so it must be possible.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first issue, you need to override `isOpaqueCube` to return false.  You'll also want to override `isFullCube` for other parts of the code, but that isn't as important for rendering.  Example:

```java
public class YourBlock {
    // ... existing code ...

    /**
     * Used to determine ambient occlusion and culling when rebuilding chunks for render
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isOpaqueCube(IBlockState state) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFullCube(IBlockState state) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Here's some info on rendering that mentions this](http://greyminecraftcoder.blogspot.com/2013/07/rendering-transparent-blocks.html).

---

Regarding your second problem, that's more complicated.  It's generally achieved via a tile entity, though you can also use block updates (which is much slower).  Good examples of this are `BlockBeacon` and `TileEntityBeacon` (for using tile entities) and `BlockFrostedIce` (for block updates).  Here's some (potentially out of date) [info on tile entities](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Basic_Tile_Entity).

Here's an (untested) example of getting an update each tick this with tile entities:

```java
public class YourBlock {
    // ... existing code ...

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of a block's tile entity class. Called on placing the block.
     */
    @Override
    public TileEntity createNewTileEntity(World worldIn, int meta) {
        return new TileEntityYourBlock();
    }
}
```

```java
/**
 * Tile entity for your block.
 * 
 * Tile entities normally store data, but they can also receive an update each
 * tick, but to do so they must implement ITickable.  So, don't forget the
 * "implements ITickable".
 */
public class TileEntityYourBlock extends TileEntity implements ITickable {
    @Override
    public void update() {
        // Your code to give potion effects to nearby players would go here

        // If you only want to do it every so often, you can check like this:
        if (this.worldObj.getTotalWorldTime() % 80 == 0) {
            // Only runs every 80 ticks (4 seconds)
        }
    }

    // The following code isn't required to make a tile entity that gets ticked,
    // but you'll want it if you want (EG) to be able to set the effect.

    /**
     * Example potion effect.
     * May be null.
     */
    private Potion effect;

    public void setEffect(Potion potionEffect) {
        this.effect = potionEffect;
    }

    public Potion getEffect() {
        return this.effect;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFromNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.readFromNBT(compound);
        int effectID = compound.getInteger("Effect")
        this.effect = Potion.getPotionById(effectID);
    }

    public void writeToNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.writeToNBT(compound);
        int effectID = Potion.getIdFromPotion(this.effect);
        compound.setInteger("Effect", effectID);
    }
}
```

```java
// This line needs to go in the main registration.
// The ID can be anything so long as it isn't used by another mod.
GameRegistry.registerTileEntity(TileEntityYourBlock.class, "YourBlock");
```